# Ложные клики в Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragment

Доброго времени суток, [RU.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)!

Пишу приложение с применением material NavigationDrawer(ND). Как вы знаете, у ND есть шапка вверху, которую отвели под информацию о пользователе. Я решил данное поле переделать под свои нужды. В итоге наткнулся на маленькую проблему.

Когда табаю по пустым местам шапки, то попадаю на фрагмент, который открыт под ND. Этого не должно быть, т.к. нужны действия со слоя ND. Поэтому появилась мысль применит

`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();`. И вместо параметра `fragment` отправлять пустой фрагмент. Это правильно ? Есть практика применения подобных вещей ?

И второй вопрос по ND: можно ли метод `onDrawerOpen` в `NavigationDrawerFragment` грузить AsyncTask'ом с запросами к БД ([для бейджей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425795/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8-%D0%B2-navigation-drawer)) и методом или AsyncTask'ом с проверкой доступа в Интернет + аутентификацию пользователя в Google ?

**UPD0** - [Material Design Navigation Drawer Activity](https://github.com/kanytu/Android-studio-material-template/tree/master/MaterialNavigationDrawerActivity) (загрузить с GitHub)

Располагается/копируется в: *[место установки]\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities*
// в шаблоне изменен тип доступа в классе NavigationDrawerDrafment
`public void selectItem(int position) { ....}`  с `private` на `public`. Это понадобилось для модернизации меню бейджами.

Comment: возможно использование нового виджета от гугл решит вашу проблему. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427306/177345

Comment: @pavlofff, нет, не решит, т.к. придется переписывать код.
Что Вы скажете по поводу нагрузки на фрагмент и подложки под ND пустого фрагмента ?

Comment: Material NavigationDrawer - это внешняя библиотека https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer?

Comment: @lsillarionov, нет. Это шаблон проекта, который я использую в Android Studio. В стоковой студии нет такого шаблона.

Comment: @web_alex так а где вы тогда его взяли? По описанию непонятно, о чем идет речь, что за material navigation drawer и где и почему там возникает проваливание событий. Понятно только то, что что-то вы делаете не так. Нужен либо код с макетами, либо хотя бы исходный вариант

Comment: @lsillarionov, обновил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-я часть вопроса**: Чтобы убрать ложный клики, нужно дописать ***всем перекрывающим*** элементам `android:clickable="true"`. 
В моем случае - корневой `layout` получил данное свойство.